# SharePoint 2013 lazy load for .click() issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

With IE 10 and Chrome 26 on Win7 x64 (**Host1**) no issues are appearing, except Firefox 20.

With IE IE 8 on Win7 x64 (**Host2**) and IE 10 on Windows Server 2012 x64 (**Host3**), there is the following issue I noticed with SharePoint 2013:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'showModalDialog' of undefined or null reference

and when I look into the code: `SP.UI.ModalDialog` (for which I call: `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(optDict);`) seems to be `undefined` here. Only few properties of `SP.UI` is available on **Host2** and **Host3**, while on **Host1** there are much more of these.

There is jQuery **.click()** event on some HTML element that triggers the function to display ModalWindow.

So it's as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#some-a-element").click(function uploadMyFile(directory)) {

            // something...

            optDict = {
                width: 800,
                height: 500,
                url: someUrl,
                title: "Upload your file"
            };

            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(optDict);

            // something else
        });

        // sumthing even here
    });

    // more code...

 </script>
```

Looking for the solution over the internet, I've found out (in here) that this might be connected to **lazy loading** of SP.js and proper usage of `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` function should solve the issue.

So in my case it should be something like

`ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(uploadMyFile, 'SP.js');`

...I guess... Right?

However, I have no idea how to achieve this with **.click()** event handler presented above - and how to arrange it in this code structure. Tried few combinations that came into my mind, but without any success...

Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap your code inside the uploadMyFile function into ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded, as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#some-a-element").click(function uploadMyFile(directory)) {

            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {    

                // something

                optDict = {
                    width: 800,
                    height: 500,
                    url: someUrl,
                    title: "Upload your file"
                };

                SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(optDict);

                // something else

            }, "sp.js");

        });

        // sumthing even here
    });

    // more code...

 </script>
```

**Notice**: There is one more gotcha here, introduced in SP2013. For published pages, the ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded will not work. Instead, you should use SP.SOD.executeFunc, which has a slightly different syntax.

Details on this can be found here: [ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded not executing after page publish](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/60522/1430)

Comment: You're right! executeFunc is something I was looking for. With this one everything works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
  var options = {
                        url : $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() + "/_layouts/15/KoellischFrameworkEMailForm/EMailVorlageBefuellen.aspx?id=" + $(el).attr("ID").replace("VorlagenTableRowId", "") + "&ElementId=" + elementId + "&ListName=" + listName
                    };
                     options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, function (result, value) {
                if (result == '1') {
                    var signatur = setzeSignatur();
                    $('input[id*=TextBoxBetreff]').val(value[0]);
                    if (signatur == null) {
                        $("#jhtm").contents().find('body').html(value[1]);
                    } else {
                        $("#jhtm").contents().find('body').html(value[1] + "<br />" + signatur);
                    }
                    $('#Vorlagen').hide();
                    $('#vorlagenButton').show();
        }
    });
                    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
                });
```