# Javascript works when on edit page but not when page is published

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I have a page on my sharepoint site, when i'm on the edit page the javascript works
however when I have published the page, the javascript doesn't work.
I have added the link to the javascript file in some embedded code. 
any help would be appreciated

Comment: this is maybe also helpful **[SharePoint 2016: JS is only working in Edit Mode](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-script-editor-only-works-in-edit-mode/)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a known issue for a publishing pages ([here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f8f40b15-3822-4eae-b15a-e18594a6d03f/spjs-does-not-load-on-publishing-pages-and-for-anonymous-users?forum=sharepointdevelopment) or [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60522/executeordelayuntilscriptloaded-not-executing-after-page-publish)), `sp.js` library is loaded in the edit mode but not in the display mode.

As part of [Minimal Download Strategy (MDS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456544(v=office.15).aspx) that was introduced in In SharePoint 2013, SharePoint JavaScript libraries  like `sp.js` are not loaded until explicitly called.

### Solution

Utilize [SP.SOD.executeFunc method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx) to load SharePoint JavaScript libraries on demand, for example:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){

    //your code goes here...

});
```

Comment: Hello Vadim where do I put the SP.SOD.executeFunc in my code? Does it go in my sp.js file or my page somewhere?

Comment: That's right, sp.js is a part of core JS library and it is getting loaded with every page in SharePoint

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the type or language attribute to any `<script>` tags being used in a Script editor web part.

`type='text/javascript'` or `language='javascript'`

For example: `<script type='text/javascript' src="js/app.js"></script>`

See [Script Editor only runs JavaScript in edit mode](http://paulryan.com.au/2014/script-editor-runs-javascript-edit-mode/)

Answer (score 0):

Is your javascript placed inside *PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel*?

If yes, check if the *pagedisplaymode* is correct!

If you want the javascript to be run in both (edit/display) just place the javascript outside the *PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel*

```
<!-- Display mode only -->
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" 
PageDisplayMode="Display">
    javascript....
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>


<!-- Edit mode only -->
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" 
PageDisplayMode="Edit">
    javascript
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

documentation to editmodepanel

> [EditmodePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.EditModePanel%28v=office.14%29.aspx)