# Page Won't Load jQuery Script After being Published

Tags: jquery, custom-masterpage, publishing-page

I'm experiencing an issue where I cannot get my jQuery script to work once a page is published.  Based on the answers below, all I need to do is simply run

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function(){
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){    
        var parent = $("#zz12_V4QuickLaunchMenu > ul > li:has('ul')");
        parent.find("span.menu-item-text:first").append("&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class='fa fa-angle-down' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
        parent.closest("li").find("> ul").hide();

        parent.click(function(){
        var childUL = $(this).closest("li").find("> ul");
        var isVisible = childUL.is(":visible");

    if (isVisible) {

  childUL.slideUp();
  }
  else {
  childUL.slideDown();

  }

  });
});
});
```

except this does not work at all. I am familiar with jQuery, less so with javascript.  So I do not know how to call my jQuery inside this javascript function.  It looks to me that '$' is being used by another library, how do I ensure it is used inside of this function?  Thanks.

Comment: if you try with $(function(){ alert("hello world"); });   just like that with no "noConflict" or anything, does it work? Also are you sure your JSfile that contains the jquery code is loaded after the call to the jQuery file?

Comment: yes. it works perfectly fine until i publish the page. so i'm wondering if there is some other sp js that interferes when i publish the page.

Comment: This is very common issue with MDS in SP 2013...Vadim answered this question a while back here.. Have a look http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104849/javascript-works-when-on-edit-page-but-not-when-page-is-published

Comment: Or disable the MDS feature, looks like its gone in the Modern Experiences anyway

Comment: Thanks @RansherSingh.  I attempted to utilize SP.SOD to load a simple alert("Working"); and that did not work either.  Currently, I have my script loaded in the <head> portion of my custom html masterpage with just a normal script link.  Would it be best to try it with the ScriptLink instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes across this, the issue was that SharePoint uses two different IDs for Display and Edit modes in the topNav module.  Changing the selector worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like below code:

```
    // wait until jquery load is complete
    function waituntilJqueryLoad() {
       if (window.$)
          isLoaded();
       else
          setTimeout(function () { waituntilJqueryLoad() }, 50);
   }

  // Execute Script when DOM is ready
  function isLoaded() {

$(document).ready(function () {
    //write your code here
});


   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("waituntilJqueryLoad");
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Unfortunately, this didn't work for me either but I appreciate your time all the same.

Comment: never mind.. i'm an idiot; i realized the masterpage linked to the file of the same name in a different site collection.  bangs head on desk.

Comment: Waiting for the page to load using setTimeout isn't really the good approach to follow..

Comment: Thanks @MohamedDerhalli , i have just given an example, but instead of using setTimeout, we can use another thing also as i preferred to use getScript method.

Comment: @user2004758 Please mark it as answer if it helped you :)

Comment: @AbhishekKumarSeth the code wasn't working bc sp uses 2 diff div ids for the quicklaunch menu in edit mode & display mode.  changing the selector worked for me but ty for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourFunction, "SP.js");
    function yourFunction() {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        //now you have the context, you can do anything here.
    }
});
```

This will wait for the jQuery to be loaded, then it will execute everything else, you should not load SharePoint files first, then wait for document to load using jQuery.

Comment: thanks - this does not work either.  i get an error that says object does not support property or method 'ready'... which is weird as hell.

Comment: In which browser are you having this error? Did you try different browsers?

Comment: yes, i tested in both IE and Chrome.  the script works in Edit mode, when I Check It In, and then it ceases to work when the page is published regardless of the browser.

Comment: How are you referencing this script? How's jQuery referenced and where?

Comment: jQuery is referenced in the master page with a ScriptLink with LoadAfterUI set to true. The above js is also referenced in the master page but via a normal html script tag.  The script tag is placed after the jQuery and everything is in the head of the document.

Comment: hm, just had a thought. i am wondering if i need to publish the js file to be able to view it properly on a published pg?  my assumption was no since i have SCA rights [though i know this is true for other users to see things properly] but i'm just trying to cover all bases.