# SharePoint App Part TypeError: SP.SOD is undefined

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app-part, sp.sod

Visual Studio generates some code when you create a new add-in. I want to develop a app part which shows the current user. I added a new web-part in Visual Studio and modified the code from `App.js` and from `Pages/AppPart.aspx`.

**App.js**

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', initializePage);
});

function initializePage() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

    // This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getUserName();
    });

    // This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get the current users information
    function getUserName() {
        context.load(user);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call is successful
    // It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
    function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
        $('#message').text('Hello ' + user.get_title());
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call fails
    function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
    }
}
```

Here I've replaced the call `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` with `SP.SOD.executeFunc`, because [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60522/executeordelayuntilscriptloaded-not-executing-after-page-publish) said it could be a solution.

---

**Pages/AppPart.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming" runat="server" />

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Set the style of the client web part page to be consistent with the host web.
        (function () {
            'use strict';

            var hostUrl = '';
            var link = document.createElement('link');
            link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
            if (document.URL.indexOf('?') != -1) {
                var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var p = decodeURIComponent(params[i]);
                    if (/^SPHostUrl=/i.test(p)) {
                        hostUrl = p.split('=')[1];
                        link.setAttribute('href', hostUrl + '/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hostUrl == '') {
                link.setAttribute('href', '/_layouts/15/1033/styles/themable/corev15.css');
            }
            document.head.appendChild(link);
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p id="message">
            <!-- The following content will be replaced with the user name when you run the app - see App.js -->
            initializing...
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

However I still get the error `TypeError: SP.SOD is undefined` in the Console. The file `sp.js` is loaded properly. Any solutions? When I call the app itself via its url, it works fine, it just fire this error when inserting the app part into sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Since a App Part is included as `<iframe>` it cannot access the javascript files, that have been added to the parent document. `SP.SOD` is defined in `init.js`, so in my case I had to include that in the file `Pages/AppPart.aspx`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
```