# SP.js is not loaded in page

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I am using this piece of code on a couple of sites within my SharePoint Online environment:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
    alert('test');
    //my code follows
});
```

Although, this code doesn't work on some pages (I don't get the alert)

I've checked in the browser, SP.js is actually loaded. Any ideas???

Comment: see https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2015/10/05/key-points-to-know-when-using-sp-sod-executefunc-and-sp-sod-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded/

Comment: and: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58503/sp-sod-how-to-use-correctly

Comment: Is it on SharePoint-Hosted app client webpart ?

Comment: @RonakPatel it's in the CEWP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sorted this out.

I was comparing this site with other site where this code is working and I found out that the problem was this site feature.

> Minimal Download Strategy
>
> A technique that delivers a faster and more fluid page navigation experience, in pages and site templates that support it, by downloading and rendering only those portions of a page that are changing.

It was active on my site, so the script didn't work.

I switched it off and everything is fine now.

Strange thing is that I'm the only one developing on this Site Collection and I didn't modify any of the site features so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
alert('test');
   //code
}, "sp.js");
```

Comment: Doesn't alert anything :/ The strange thing is, I have some buttons within the page, when I click on them, I get the alert

Comment: Have you checked syntax is correct. Alert without sp code and check.