# Javascript execution delay until sp.js and ps.js loads

Tags: javascript, csom, project-server, ms-project

I am trying to get project list from my project portal using JavaScript. I wrote a script that should do the job:

```
var projects;

// Geting JS library responsible for Project API 
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "/_layouts/15/sp.js";
jQuery("body").append(script);
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "/_layouts/15/ps.js";
jQuery("body").append(script);

console.log('SP.SOD.loadMultiple(["sp.js", "ps.js"], callback); is executed.');
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['sp.js', 'ps.js'], function(){
    console.log('sp.js and ps.js was loaded succesfully.');

    projContext = PS.ProjectContext.get_current();
    projects = projContext.get_projects();
    projContext.load(projects, 'Include(Name, Description, StartDate, Id)');

    projContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
});

function onQuerySucceeded () {
    console.log('Callback onQuerySucceeded in LoadProjectsProperties was fired.');

    var enumerator = projects.getEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var project = enumerator.get_current();
        console.log(project.get_name());
    }
}

function onQueryFailed () {
    console.log('Callback onQueryFailed in LoadProjectsProperties was fired.');
}
```

In console it shows

```
'SP.SOD.loadMultiple(["sp.js", "ps.js"], callback); is executed.'

unreachable code after return statement[Learn More] (on sp.ribbon.js)
TypeError: this.$D_2 (on cui.js)
```

and this message:

```
'sp.js and ps.js was loaded succesfully.'
```

is never displayed which means that callback for loadMultiple functions is never running. Everything is enclosed in jQuery ready function and jQuery no conflict mode.

Does anyone had similar problem? What is a solution to load both scripts before running a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl', loadMyProjectFiles);

function loadMyProjectFiles(){

    // Getting JS library responsible for Project API 
    SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
    SP.SOD.registerSod('PS.ProjectContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('ps.js'));
    SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'PS.ProjectContext'], function(){

        console.log('sp.js has been loaded..');
        console.log('ps.js has been loaded..');
        console.log('sp.js and ps.js was loaded succesfully.');

        projContext = PS.ProjectContext.get_current();
        projects = projContext.get_projects();
        projContext.load(projects, 'Include(Name, Description, StartDate, Id)');

        projContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

    });
}


function onQuerySucceeded () {
    console.log('Callback onQuerySucceeded in LoadProjectsProperties was fired.');

    var enumerator = projects.getEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var project = enumerator.get_current();
        console.log(project.get_name());
    }
}

function onQueryFailed () {
    console.log('Callback onQueryFailed in LoadProjectsProperties was fired.');
}
```

Comment: Hi Gautam,

Thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately it gives the following error now:

    jQuery.Deferred exception: SP.Utilities.Utility is undefined @https://connect.concare.net/pwa/projects.aspx?...
    TypeError: SP.Utilities.Utility is undefined

both on current page. Do you know why this is happening? I am using it as script editor web part on standard project.aspx page.

Comment: can you check the updated code ?

Comment: try running this first `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',<answers code>);`

Comment: Ah! you beat me to it :P

Comment: The solutions worked! 

Thanks a lot, can you provide me with some pages/courses about how SP.SOD functions/ JavaScript libraries work in SharePoint? I am new to this topic, and this is pretty hard for me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to know that :) 

Follow this link - Great answers provided here !

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58503/sp-sod-how-to-use-correctly