# Need to call SP.SOD.registerSod twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sp.sod

I have created two functional Units on my application page. One comes along in a separate script, the other is embedded via script editor web part.

The external script is called fiirst all the time an I am priming jQuery using `SP.SOD.registerSod('jquery', 'cdn-path/to/jquery');`. When the script in my script Editor web part gets hit, I use `SP.SOD.executeFunc('jquery', callback);` to assure jQuery is loaded and I can execute my callback.

This does not work, though.
When I reach the second call to `SP.SOD.executeFunc()` jQuery is already loaded, the callback just does not get called.
However if I prime the same jQuery script again using `SP.SOD.registerSod('jquery2', path/to/same/jquerycdn)` everything works. What am I missing? How can I use jQuery across the scripts?

Comment: Did you check this answer https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58503/sp-sod-how-to-use-correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

SOD (Script on Demand) and the MDS feature (Minimal Download Strategy) are not the easiest.

Not answering your question:

Use the Chrome Extension SharePoint Editor **once**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd?hl=en

to load jQuery with a UserCustomAction ScriptLink

That will load jQuery early on on **every** page in the SiteCollection

and save you some SOD & MDS headaches

Comment: Thank you for your engagement. I just don't get why the callback is not being called (please see question again, I added some Information). Can MDS be disabled?

Comment: Yes, MDS is a Site Collection feature. If you disable it and your callback works you know MDS is interfering (or better said: your SOD code is wrong) That is why using a ScriptLink to load jQuery **always** saves a whole lot of headaches

Comment: MDS is disabled. Currently I can only change individual site features, nevertheless the Feature is disabled on the desired site. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Not for your callback issue, had too many headaches with it in the past. Load jQuery the easy/fastest/safest way with that Chrome Extensions, if you want to scope it to the Web : see http://johnliu.net/blog/2015/12/the-safest-future-proof-way-to-brand-your-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-online

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use Chrome due to restrictions in the company. So I will use my Approach which is ugly but works. Thank you

Comment: That company also still heats the building with coal? The last link I posted has nothing to do with Chrome.. it requires you to add ASPX pages to (every SiteCollection you need to)  add UserCustomActions

Comment: Now I get you! Your answer is covering actually more than I need, but gives me a good idea of how can create a custom action. If you provide it as the answer I can accept it! Thank you
And no, we don't use coal anymore :)